# SSRS Looking for Non Existent Shared Dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

What could cause one user to be initiating an old version of the report?

I have a report that runs perfectly when logged directly on the reporting services server.

When run from the LAN it gives an error that one of the parameter data sets execution failed.  The error message shows that the parameter is pointing to a data set that was used in the report months ago but is no longer currently used.  Looking at the properties of the report in reporting services everything is pointed to a valid shared data set.

Answer (score 0):

The .rdl file has a connection string saved in it. This is what you connect to during development and it is the default connection. When you upload the file to the reporting services server, you have the option of overriding that and pointing it to a shared data source. In other words, the "old" data source has always been built into that .rdl file (you can look at the XML to confirm this), but it is being overridden on the server.

Hope this helps clear up the confusion.